# Twitter Bootstrap: Text in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

According to the twitter bootstrap [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar), I should be able to "Wrap strings of text in a `<p>` tag for proper leading and color." When I do this, at any level under `navbar` it simply doesn't inherit any of the `navbar` classes. Wrapping the string in `<a>` tags renders it but it shouldn't be an anchor.

The string I'm trying to render is `"Logged in as ... "`.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You have to include a class along with your `p` tag inside of your navbar, like so:

```
<p class="navbar-text">Logged in as</p>
```

Comment: @capncaveman the twitter folks did not include that weird enough, but you can see it on their page examples.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to use `<p class="nav navbar-text">` to get correct formatting.

Comment: Thanks for that! FYI @eaj w/3.3.6 I did not need .nav . Question: Is there a standard Bootstrap class that disable the <p> text from selection?

Comment: @MatthewCornell none that I am aware of but you can "fake" it by styling the `::selection` color to that of the background and resetting the `cursor` property to default on hover, like so `cursor: default;`.

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed in [issue 2799](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2799).

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `<span class="navbar-text">` for the format to level with the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers or comments worked for me (latest one was 6+ years old), but what worked for me was the following:

1. I had to use the `<span>` tag, not `<p>`
2. I had to include the `"nav-item"` class on my list element itself

My final working code looks like this:

```
<li class="nav-item"><span class="navbar-text"><h5>{{first_name}}</h5></span></li>
```

Take my word for it, but the word "Sally" below does not change to hyperlink when hovered.

[image]